# How does the Brita LED work?

Tags: power-supply, led, sensor

Specifically, I'm talking about this product here...

[Brita Faucet Filter](https://www.brita.com/products/faucet-water-filter-system/advanced-white-white/)

It has an LED that blinks when the water is running. It blinks red, yellow, or green to indicate filter quality (maybe) - but it seems to have no power source. So, my specific question is what powers the LED? And, I would also like to know what it's measuring?

It is frustrating to Google this because people don't seem to care how things work, and the phrase is equal to "What does it do" and all I can find is "It shows you the water quality" - well, that's not how it works. Brita claims the filter lasts for 100 gallons, but I'm not sure about that, it seems as though the LED turns to red based on the amount of time, but to do that it would need a constant power supply and I don't see one.

Comment: Take one apart...

Comment: I don't have an answer, but mine stopped working soon after I bought it and after emailing customer service they wanted info to identify it i did not have as I threw the box away after purchase, and they never responded again. I just now removed the rubber cap and they seems to be a tiny circuit board underneath, maybe a batt underneath? I am going to remove it and see. What can it hurt, it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: It's powered by a CR2032 battery - there's a little tray you can slide out to replace it.  They last about 3 years.  Top Tip:  Whatever you do, don't insert the batter tray without a battery in... or you'll have to disassemble the unit to get it back out.  This is because there are two metal contacts that get caught in the tray when there's no battery in it.

Answer (score 3):

If an average faucet flows at 2 gpm (according to the US EPA), and the filter does not significantly reduce that flow, then 100 gallons is about 50 minutes.

An inexpensive  CR2032 is rated at 230mAh, which is more than enough. Chances are it's something even cheaper like a stack of a few LR44 button cells. That can also be used to retain information.

The other options (electrochemical action, paddle wheel generator, miniature nuclear reactor) would be too expensive or would cause contamination.

Comment: +1 especially for contamination issues. Also reliability might be an issue; after a long holiday hard water may have left some scaling within such a device. A battery would be immune to that.

Answer (score 2):

Brita's documentation says that it counts time and "pours", apparently detecting water flow.

My guess as to the power source would be one of two: either replacement filters also contain a battery for the electronics, or else the power comes from a tiny water-flow-powered generator (which would also serve as a "pour detector"). That latter seems very likely - the unit could be storing its count in semivolatile memory while it's still powered by water flow, so the count would still be available later. Power consumption may be extremely low.

Nobody can know for sure without disassembly, though.

Comment: "... or else the power comes from a tiny water-flow-powered generator (which would also serve as a "pour detector"). That latter seems very likely" I would say that seems very *unlikely* as the BOM cost for what you described would be way too high.

Comment: @Patrick I'm not so sure. A generator is no more than a tiny brushed DC motor with an impeller, and little brushed DC motors are dead cheap.

BOM cost is immaterial. They just pass it on to the consumer.

Answer (score 1):

Spehro Pefhany has explained that a small battery is sufficient to power the filter.

This [Amazon Brita Faucet Filter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000DBIKH) review says:

> ... We just purchased a new one with the brass threads because the old
>   plastic one's battery has died and does not show the filter life
>   status. ...

Which seems like a strong indicator.

The circuitry may be as simple as a 'timer'. The Brita [Reading your indicator](https://www.brita.com/using-your-brita/using-your-brita/) site says:

> Green: Your filter is working.
>
> Half Red and Green: Replace filter soon. Your filter cartridge has two
>   weeks or approximately 20 gallons of life left.
>
> Red: Your filter cartridge has reached the end of its life and needs
>   to be replaced now.

So it only needs to measure how long water is flowing. That is my expectation.

However this patent for a [Water conductivity monitor for a water purification system](http://www.google.com/patents/US5527450) suggests that their is an electronic comparison of tap water with filtered water.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the patents.

CA2573448 A1 (Moen Inc., 2007 Canada) describes an LED, printed circuit board, and connection to a battery.  This patent did not specify what the LED color is determined by, other than vague possibilities such as time elapsed or gallons passed.

US20050279676 (Zuhair Izzy et al, 2004) - ah, this one is juicier!  The description goes into detail about an impeller, counting of its rotations, and changing the LED color based on a preset cumulative flow quantity. This patent also refers to a battery.

WO2005032690 A1 (Brian Boyd et al, Water Pik, 2005) explains the use of a magnet on a turbine blade in the unit to activate a sensor.  A microprocessor keeps count, and sets the LED color according to total flow.  No mention of a battery or other power source, though.

There are other patents that may be of interest. Some focus on mechanical or system design, and only lightly brush over the topic of interest.

Comment: That's a very interesting approach, I like it! I think it's a simple timer though, because putting the same filter back in switches it back to green again. It must not be sensing the actual water quality or filter quality. Good news for me, because I use a lot less water than most people, so I'll just reset the filter once before changing it.

Answer (score -1):

An LED is a Light Emitting Diode. They have a voltage drop of 0.7V+ depending on the color they are. Like ay diode the Anode voltage must be greater than the cathode voltage for it to conduct. There must be power coming from somewhere or it wouldn't work. Most likely it's a coin cell battery connected onto a small circuit board that runs the LED and interfaces with the filter to figure out if the filter requires changing.

I would say if you're really that curious. Go buy (or find) one and take it apart.

Comment: [Check this link](http://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/165g28/eli5_how_do_the_brita_water_pitcher_sensors_work/)

Comment: This is a three color LED, and I think it's powered by the water running. Somebody has to know the answer to this. I'm not taking one apart, they cost $30.

Comment: ZOMGnerd, there's no consensus on that post, and it's a different product with different indicator behavior.

Comment: @ZOMGnerd - "... Light Emitting Diode. They have a voltage drop of 0.7V" not true. No commonly available LED has such a low voltage drop when it is emitting. Red LEDs start around 1.7V [Wikipedia LED](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LED#Colors_and_materials) says red 1.63V, yellow 2.1V, green 1.9V.

Comment: I understand this which is why there is a + sign after the V. This means it's greater than 0.7V (The Vdo of a standard diode).